# Делаем сеть

Tags: сеть

Объясните тупому. Есть компы с XP и один с WS2003. Все провода воткнуты в комуникаторы. Что теперь делать? как выбрать для каждого IP и настроить прокси и почту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мало информации для пояснений по прокси и почте. Поищите в гугле, думаю, статей найдется не мало.

Что касается адресов выбирайте из следующих диапазонов:

1. 10.0.0.0 — 10.255.255.255 (10.0.0.0/8 или 10/8),
2. 172.16.0.0 — 172.31.255.255 (172.16.0.0/12 или 172.16/12),
3. 192.168.0.0 — 192.168.255.255 (192.168.0.0/16 или 192.168/16).

Делайте совершенно произвольный выбор:

> Например:
>
> **10.10.10.0** -> будет выбранным диапазоном

Но, кое-что еще зависит от маски.

Чтобы выбрать сколько адресов вам нужно, а соответственно и маску, сосчитайте количество компьютеров в вашей сети (со всеми серверами и клиентами), а затем прибавьте два. После этого округлите число до ближайшего большего, являющегося степенью двойки, его вам и следует вычесть из 256, получите последнее число в маске.

Не буду вдаваться в подробности, для чего и почему вы сие будете делать. Работает этот алгоритм только для количества компьютеров меньше 253, для большего, совсем чуточку все сложнее, и я бы советовал тогда уже углубиться в саму идею "[почему](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR)". Хотя можете свободно ставить маску 255.255.255.0 получите максимум 253 компьютера в сети, собственно, так делают все начинающие.

> Например:
>
> 2 компьютера + 2 = 4 -> ближайшая степень двойки и есть 4 ->маска **255.255.255.252**
>
> 10 комп. + 2 = 12 -> ближайшая степень - 16 ->маска **255.255.255.240**

Далее воспользуйтесь сервисом http://ip-calculator.ru/ чтобы определить какие адреса вам можно брать, а какие нет, для выбранной вами маски.

Для наших примеров выше:

> маска **255.255.255.252**
>
> с данной маской вы можете выбирать любые диапазоны по **4** адреса (0-3, 4-7 ... 252-255), из которых нельзя брать первый и последний адреса**10.10.10.0-3** - **10.10.10.0 и 10.10.10.3** брать нельзя, *10.10.10.1 и 10.10.10.2* - можно
>
> маска **255.255.255.240**
>
> все то же самое, только уже для 16 адресов (0-15, 16-31 ... 240-255)**10.10.10.0-15** - **10.10.10.0 и 10.10.10.15** брать нельзя, *10.10.10.1-14* - можно

При выборе маски `255.255.255.0` вы можете брать любые адреса для ваших компьютеров из диапазона от 1 до 254.

На компьютерах адреса должны быть уникальны в пределах одной сети.

Comment: спасибо.Это самое понятное что я когда либо встречал

Answer (score 0):

[[@ivanov](/users/129/ivanov)](/users/129/ivanov), в двух словах этого Вам никто не объяснит, вернее объяснить можно, но толку от этого никакого не будет. Необходимо читать литературу. Ознакомьтесь [с этой лекцией](http://www.intuit.ru/department/network/netmsserver2003/) и все сами поймете, а если прочитаете и возникнут вопросы - то тогда задавайте их здесь.